# Recursion - Double each char of a string input and cut of the last char afterwards with one method

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following problem.

The recursive method public static String doSomeMagic("Test") should return:

```
TTeesstt
TTeess
TTee
TT
```

I've implemented this behaviour already like this:

```
public static String rowFunction(String s) {
    String toReturn = new String();

    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        toReturn = String.valueOf(s.charAt(0));
        toReturn += toReturn + rowFunction(s.substring(1));
    }
    return toReturn;
}

public static String doSomeMagic(String s) {
    String toReturn = new String();

    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        toReturn = rowFunction(s) + "\n" + doSomeMagic(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

How can one achieve this with just one function? Any ideas?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How should I rename it? English isn't my native language and I don't know how to precise the question's title. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh, of course. You're right. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Also, you might have better luck on code review or programmers Stack Exchange web site.

Comment: What prevents you from moving the logic of rowFunction into doSomeMagic?

Comment: @MichaelT How could I then call it recursively as I do right now? I'm aware of the fact that this can be simply achieved with a loop but I was just wondering if it is possible to do this without any loop AND only one method and if - how?

Comment: I guess they sent you back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you wanted to do this without a loop and in one function call. You can probably clean this up a lot more. Here it is:

```
public static String doSomeMagic(String s) {
    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        return sb.append(s.replaceAll("(\\S)", "$1$1"))
                 .append("\n")
                 .append(doSomeMagic( s.replaceAll(".$", "") )
                 .toString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer but this is great! I'm a little bit ashamed that this approach with RegEx didn't come to mind yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do it in one function, just iterate over the string rather than calling another recursive function.

```
public static String doSomeMagic(String s) {
    String doubled = new String();
    if (s.length() == 0) return s;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        doubled += s.substring(i,i+1) + s.substring(i,i+1)
    return doubled + "\n" + doSomeMagic(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: Ouch.  Please, if you are doing either `new String()` or `double += ...`, please, please, please use a `StringBuilder` instead.  Please look into the memory use of this approach if s is 1024 characters long.

Comment: Oh, I agree. I was just trying to use as much of the OP's code as I could to simplify things.

Comment: @MichaelT Is it also the wrong approach in my code? And if so - why? Is calling s += s + "abc" not the same as s = s + s + "abc"? Or should one use (Stringbuilder sb) sb.append("xy"); sb.append(sb.toString); sb.append("abc"); instead?

Comment: In a loop, each time you go through that you are creating a new string and discarding the old one.  If the String was 8 characters, once through that for loop you'd have the following length strings created and discarded: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14... and then the 16... but the 16 would be appended to... ug... the return value of the recursive return value. You'd be using megabytes of space when running a string of 1024 characters long.  Thus, the StringBuilder, allowing you to work with a mutable string and manipulate it rather than creating an immutable string each time through the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Quick solution could be like

```
testMethod(string ip){
    if(ip.length()==1){
        ip=ip.toUppercase();
    }
    For(int i=0;i<ip.length()-1;i++){
        System.out.print(ip.charAt(i)+""+ip.charAt(i));
    }
    if(ip.length()>1){
        System. out. println();
        testMethod(ip.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it...  But should work fairly

Comment: I want it to be fully recursive, not iterative. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: It is recursive with the call of testMethod

Comment: Then easiest would be to have function like`testMethod(string ip, int current Index, int iteration Counter)` current index will tell which character to print and you keep incrementing iteration counter till its equal to length of string